# Отобразить кнопку как ссылку

Tags: html, css

Кнопка должна отобразиться как ссылка (нет фона + подчеркивание), но самое главное - если она не влазит по ширине, то должна обтекать текст, а не переходить на новую строку.

Пример:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
.box button,
.box .button{
  display: inline;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>word</span>
  <span>word</span>
  <button>button button button button</button>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="box">
  <span>word</span>
  <span>word</span>
  <span class="button">button button button button</span>
</div>
```

Первый `.box` как получается сейчас, второй `.box` как надо мне.

Comment: Возможно вам помогут следующая информация W3: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp ++ https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_buttons.asp ++ https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_animate_buttons.asp

Comment: Вопрос в другом - а зачем вам, в таком случае, кнопка в целом? Если я не ошибаюсь, кнопки не умеют "переноситься". :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

`<a href="ссылка">текст ссылки</a>`

Comment: В итоге так и сделал

Comment: @Skywave, если это вам помогло, отметьте ответом

Comment: я подожду еще ответ с вариантом стилизации тега button

Comment: @Skywave, проще стилизировать тег `a` под `button`.

Answer (score -1):

Не совсем понял что вам нужно, есть свойство `white-space: nowrap;` которое запретит перенос на новую строку.

Comment: Не совсем то. Видимо автору нужно, чтобы часть кнопки осталась на первой строке, а часть отобразилась на второй.

Comment: @Eanmos, Совершенно верно, в примере по ссылке показано как должно быть

Comment: @Eanmos насколько я знаю, то невозможно. :)

Comment: @Skywave на ruSO есть встроенный сниппет, так что выносить пример на другой сайт - не лучший вариант. Зачем пользователей утруждать? :)